# product of digits not including 0 on C

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b,c;
    b=1;
    a=0;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    while (a>0)
    {
        c=a%10;
        if (c==0) 
            b=b*1; 
        else {
            b=b*(a%10); 
            a=a/10;
        }
    }
    printf("Proizvedenie: %d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

It doesnt work when I add 0 in any position of number, but i added if and dont know why it doesnt work, cycle just does not end, pls help

```
01234 - 24; Right
1234 - 24; Right
12304 - doesnt work
12340 - doesnt work
```

WHY PLS HELP =(

Comment: `b = b * 1` doesn't do anything, why do you need that?

Comment: When you typed `01234`, the integer you got was `1234`.  Type `int` is represented internally as an integer, a number, *not* as a string of decimal digits.

Comment: replace `b=b*1;` with `a=a/10;`

Comment: In the `c==0` case, you don't do the `a=a/10;` thing, so you're going to get stuck.

Comment: can someone just rewrite my programm so i could see what my mistake is? i dnt know english well so i cant read ur comments and understate everything in them =(

Comment: As soon as you have a zero the loop becomes infinite, and if you thought-debug your code and walk through it with a trivial input (`101`) you'll see why. `a` is never modified when the zero is encountered, so the zero will *always* be encountered thereafter.

Comment: @kek4a "can someone just rewrite my programm so i could see what my mistake is? " --> No.  Good answers are for you **and** others.

Answer (score 3):

You're only dividing `a` by 10 when the current digit is not 0.  When the digit is 0 `a` stays the same and you and up in an infinite loop.

Move the update of `a` to outside of the `if` block.  Also, `b=b*1` is a no-op, so you can remove that.

```
while (a>0)
{
    c=a%10;
    if (c!=0) {
        b=b*c; 
    }
    a=a/10;
}
```

Comment: I changed my division line to use `/=` so our answers wouldn't be almost word-for-word identical. :)

Comment: what if a is < 0

Comment: @0___________ Then the `while` wont be executed and the result will be 1

Comment: @SupportUkraine is it a correct result? What about `0`

Comment: @SupportUkraine is `1` the correct result for `0`? "same, same"

Answer (score 2):

You're only doing `a = a/10` in the `else` block. So when you get to a `0` digit, you stop dividing by 10 and get stuck in an infinite loop.

Take that line out of the `if/then`, since it needs to be done every time.

```
    while (a>0)
    {
        c=a%10;
        if (c!=0) {
            b *= c;
        }
        a /= 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned int product(int x)
{
    int result = !!x;
    while(x)
    {   
        if(x % 10) result *= abs(x % 10);
        x /= 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

```
int main(void)
{
    int testData[] = {0, 1234, 12304, 12340, -1234, -12304, -012340  /* <- octal number!! */};

    for(int x = 0; x < sizeof(testData)/sizeof(testData[0]); x ++)
        printf("%d - %u\n", testData[x], product(testData[x]));
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/T8T1a5YEE

1. Use functions.
2. integers can be negative as well
3. You need to handle zero too.

In your code:

```
    c=a%10;
    if (c==0) 
        b=b*1; 
    else {
        b=b*(a%10); 
        a=a/10;
    }
```

you need to move `a = a / 10` outside the `if` as it is only executed when  `a % 10` is not zero. If it is, `a` does not change and you are in an infinitive loop

Comment: Any comment silent DV-ter.  Do you have a bad day or something?

Comment: Good handling of `x <= 0`.  `abs()` only needed in the `return`, not the loop.  `product()` could avoid type proliferation and return `int` as the product will not exceed `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Tip: at 50k rep, no need for [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73818539/product-of-digits-not-including-0-on-c#comment130346589_73818602), it just distracts from a good answer.  Uncommented DVs are [WOAD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/%28like%29%20water%20off%20a%20duck%27s%20back)

Comment: "In your code:" portion deserves to come first to address OP's key problem.

Answer (score 1):

Others have noted the flaw in your code (location of `a=a/10;` inside `else` code block.

Here is a branchless way to achieve your objective. "Branching" (using an `if()` conditional) can make code run much slower when the processor's pipeline prediction turns out to be wrong. When processing millions (or billions) of data items, this may be a significant cost in time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int a = 0, prod = 1;

    if( scanf( "%d", &a ) != 1 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "scanf failed\n" );
        return 1;
    }

    for( a = abs(a); a; a /= 10 ) {
        int r = a%10;
        prod *= r+(r==0); // branchless technique
    }

    printf( "Proizvedenie: %d\n", prod );

    return 0;
}
```

```
54300012
Proizvedenie: 120
```

When the value of `r` is one of 1-9, `r==0` has the value 0.
When the value of `r` is 0 and `r==0` has the value 1.
So the 10 different rhs values can be 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 or 9.